# Netbeans Tool Options won't open

Tags: c++, netbeans

This question has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625217/netbeans-tools-options-wont-work-after-installing-support-for-c[/url] However I didn't find any offered solutions helpful. I installed the C/C++ plugin, and now the Tool options won't open. When I try I get a NoSuchMethodError exception. I'm still quite new to coding so I would appreciate fairly detailed help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not a c++ problem.
That exception is a java exception , it cannot find the "Method" that's being called when you click that gui menu.
Please reinstall netbeans it does happen quite a bit.